# Consistency Between MongoDB and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, mongodb, rabbitmq

I'm writing a system that will leverage Mongo for persistence and RabbitMQ for a message bus/event queueing, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to be resilient to failures on the publication side.

There are three scenarios I can think of:

1. Everything works - consistent
2. Everything fails - consistent
3. Part works, whichever happens later is out of date - **inconsistent**

The last case is the one I'm interested in, and I'm curious to know how others have solved the issue, given that XA isn't an option (and I wouldn't want the performance overhead anyway).

There are a couple of solutions I can think of:

1. Add a "lastEvent" (or some similar) field to the Mongo document. On a periodic interval, scan for documents where lastEvent < lastUpdated, and fire an event (this requires an extra update for every change, and loses context of the "old" document in the case of an update)
2. Fire the event in Rabbit **before** persisting in Mongo, and allow safe handling of events that may not have actually happened (really dislike this approach)

Could anyone else shed some light on how to provide some sort of consistency across a persistence layer and message bus?

Comment: How about 3) Move persistence from the queue publisher to a separate queue subscriber service, and only let the persistence service remove the message from the queue.

Comment: @PaulHicks That's my personal favorite approach, but it now heavily complicates simple lookups. Things that are created may not be immediately available.

Comment: What about [performing two phase commits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** is never a good idea, the notion of "last X time" falls over as soon as you introduce multi-threaded or multi-process systems, and when that "time" is generated (if some requests take longer to process then others, then the "later" time might be written before the "earlier" times to the persistent store)

**2** Is basically [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning), and it's a pattern that works very well for designing fault tolerant systems if done properly

Comment: I get the approach of idempotence, and am comfortable implementing it. What I dislike is the possibility of events existing that never happened (an event saying something was created when persistence failed). This means that every consumer now has to somehow verify that the thing actually occurred

Comment: @ColinM, typically what I've seen is reliably writing to persistent storage with a "tx id" first, and then generating events for that "tx id" as a means for implementing Idempotence.  If you simply adhere to something like this, recovery becomes trivial, i.e. "replay all the events generated on node 1 from the last 2 hours", etc.